# SQL return custom groups with 0 entries

Tags: sql, grouping

I have a query that I'm dumping into a bar graph RDLC. I'd like the query to do all the heavy lifting. Right now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN a.sc < 50 THEN '1: Less than 50' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 50 
              AND a.sc < 100 THEN '2: 50 - 100' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 100 
              AND a.sc < 150 THEN '3: 100 - 150' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 150 
              AND a.sc < 200 THEN '4: 150 - 200' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 200 
              AND a.sc < 250 THEN '5: 200 - 250' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 250 THEN '6: Greater than 250' 
         ELSE '7: Unable to calculate' 
       END AS [range]
FROM   (SOME_SUB_QUERY) AS a
ORDER BY [range]
```

As you can see I have some custom defined grouping. A sample result set would look something like this:

```
[ID]     [range]
18       4: 150 - 200
1237     6: Greater than 250
665      7: Unable to calculate
121      7: Unable to calculate
```

My RDLC is grouping the results by range and then making a bar graph. The issue is that the bar graph is missing groups if there are no items in the group.

Given the results from above I would like the query to return the following so that the graph will always have all the groups:

```
[count]     [range]
0           1: Less than 50
0           2: 50 - 100
0           3: 100 - 150
1           4: 150 - 200
0           5: 200 - 250
1           6: Greater than 250
2           7: Unable to calculate
```

I'm assuming that I need to wrap the query in another query that does the group by and adds the empty groups but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If so what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that SC is an integer:

```
Select Ranges.Name
    , Count( Z.SomeNonNullableCol )
From    (
        Select '1: Less than 50'  As Name, 0 As Min, 49 As Max
        Union All Select '2: 50 - 100', 50, 99
        Union All Select '3: 100 - 150', 100, 149
        Union All Select '4: 150 - 200', 150, 199
        Union All Select '5: 200 - 250', 200, 259 
        Union All Select '6: Greater than 250', 250, 2147483647
        Union All Select '7: Unable to calculate', -2147483648, -1
        ) As Ranges
    Left Join ( Some Subquery ) As Z
        On Z.SC Between Ranges.Min And Ranges.Max
            Or ( Z.SC Is Null And Ranges.Max = -1 )
Group By Ranges.Name
```

Comment: I think the problem is that if there are no values where `a.sc <50` then that "range" won't appear on the report with a zero count

Comment: @Conrad Fix - I see. Yes, you need the groups enumerated and left joined to the data.

Comment: @Conrad Frix - Thanks for the heads up. I've reworked my answer and given you a +1.

Answer (score 3):

You might try this. This allows you to create a virtual look up that you `left join` on. Then you can group by rtext and count the results of a in your RDLC.

If you DB supports it `PIVOT` or a `CTE` might make it cleaner

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN a.sc < 50 THEN '1: Less than 50' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 50 
              AND a.sc < 100 THEN '2: 50 - 100' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 100 
              AND a.sc < 150 THEN '3: 100 - 150' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 150 
              AND a.sc < 200 THEN '4: 150 - 200' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 200 
              AND a.sc < 250 THEN '5: 200 - 250' 
         WHEN a.sc >= 250 THEN '6: Greater than 250' 
         ELSE '7: Unable to calculate' 
       END AS [range] 
FROM   (SELECT '1: Less than 50' AS rtext 
        UNION 
        SELECT '2: 50 - 100' 
        UNION 
        SELECT '3: 100 - 150' 
        UNION 
        SELECT '4: 150 - 200' 
        UNION 
        SELECT '5: 200 - 250' 
        UNION 
        SELECT '6: Greater than 250' 
        UNION 
        SELECT '7: Unable to calculate') range 
       LEFT JOIN some_sub_query AS a 
         ON range.rtext = ( CASE 
                              WHEN a.sc < 50 THEN '1: Less than 50' 
                              WHEN a.sc >= 50 
                                   AND a.sc < 100 THEN '2: 50 - 100' 
                              WHEN a.sc >= 100 
                                   AND a.sc < 150 THEN '3: 100 - 150' 
                              WHEN a.sc >= 150 
                                   AND a.sc < 200 THEN '4: 150 - 200' 
                              WHEN a.sc >= 200 
                                   AND a.sc < 250 THEN '5: 200 - 250' 
                              WHEN a.sc >= 250 THEN '6: Greater than 250' 
                              ELSE '7: Unable to calculate' 
                            END ) 
ORDER  BY [range]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went with the other one since it is a little more concise.